# Get (access) class from its field

Tags: java, class, reflection, field

Fairly new to Java as well as SO. Here's my question:

Suppose x is an instance of a Class X. And y is an attribute (field) of X. If I pass "x.y" in a function f, is there a way to access x?

Example:

```
Class Person
{
    public Girl girl; //Girl itself is another class
}

public void function1(Girl g)
{
     //body
}

Person p = new Person();
p.girl = new Girl();
function1(p.girl);
```

Now, I want to access p in the function. (Something like a "previous" pointer in a linked list).

Looked around and found something called Reflection. But that doesn't help, really. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not valid java. There is no such thing as a function that does not belong to a class. A function can refer to its local instance of its class by referring to `this` - which is how you would refer to the instance of `Person` from inside your function (method in Java but w/e).

Comment: `I want to access ... in the function` Then add it as a parameter.

Comment: I have just typed what is needed. Assume that function1 is part of another class where all the processing is happening. And Person, Girl and this Process class is a part of the same package.

Comment: Why not just alter the method to accept a Person?

Comment: @bcsb1001, gnomed - I do not want to do that. I'm trying to type a generic function, since I have different classes like Person. But all of them have Girl as an attribute. And I'm trying to work without using any kind of inheritance, so cannot create those classes as parent classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no. Unless the Girl object is specifically designed to have a reference to its parent (you see that a lot in GUI objects in java). But that is up to whoever designed the class. Much like your example of a "previous pointer" that relies on the developer implementing a "previous pointer" in the first place. The developer could just as easily have used a singly linked list with no previous pointer.

So in short. It depends on the objects you're using. Reflection is not the answer here. Reflection is more about accessing things via their string names and inspecting members of a class.

Comment: How could I create such an object? That would involve creating a field Person in the Girl class and linking them with each other, right?

Comment: Correct. Typically it is named a "parent" reference. There is a lot of good java practice being skimmed over here though depending what you plan to do. Fields in java should rarely be public, etc... are you using an IDE? If not, I would recommend getting one and checking out the warnings.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. It's an assignment which is supposed to make us appreciate OOP. -_- So there are many restrictions. Thanks, though. :)

Comment: Ah, in the future, please tag stack overflow questions that are assignments as "homework" you'll still get good answers, but people will know its for learning and give you less trouble with the tiny details.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can reference, like a linked list, provided the reference is available. Take a look at this program. Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

```
public class Person
{

    String personName;
    static class Girl 
    {
        Person girlParent;
        String girlName;

        public Girl(String name, Person parent)
        {
            girlName = name;
            girlParent = parent;
        }
    }

    public Person(String name)
    {
        personName = name;
    }

    public static void function(Girl girl)
    {
        System.out.println("The girl's name is "+girl.girlName);
        System.out.println("The girl's parent is "+girl.girlParent.personName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person julia = new Person("Julia");
        Girl nancy = new Girl("Nancy", julia);
        function(nancy);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
The girl's name is Nancy
The girl's parent is Julia
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I guess gnomed's answer was similar. :)

Comment: @Mallika, :) No problem. If my answer helped you, could you at least mark it as the answer?

Comment: I would not recommend showing an inner static class to a beginner... I realize you did it for the sake of keeping the code in the same file, but this is not easy to follow for someone new to the language.